# How to filter one element of JSON array when specific value exist in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have const allAlertsData which is JSON array with elements as objects. I want to filter specific element of array once it's property trainId === idTrain.
const idTrain is taken from useParams.
[image]

So out of whole allAlertsData, I want to filter out only element[0] if idTrain will be TLK-12345.

Can You please suggest how to filter only one element of JSON array based on matching it's specific property ?

Comment: Do you know [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: @Manfred whilst the filter method will return the desired element, it will return it as an Array. The question specifically wanted to filter out only one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `find()` method of an `Array`:

```js
const foundAlert = allAlertsData.find(alert => alert.trainId === trainId)
```

The find method will return the first element where the provided testing function evaluates truthy. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find))